# Table doesn't exist after upgrade

Tags: database, upgrade, low-variables, ee2-upgrades, database-error

I upgraded from EE 2.9.2 to 2.11.5

Everything is working good, except I get this error when I view a News entry at domain.com/news/news-entry-title:

```
Error Number: 1146

Table 'db_name.exp_low_variables_grid_field_27' doesn't exist

SELECT * FROM (`exp_low_variables_grid_field_27`) WHERE `entry_id` IN ('263') ORDER BY `row_order` asc

Filename: models/grid_model.php

Line Number: 413
```

This happens on every News entry, not just `263`.

I can confirm there is **no** `exp_low_variables_grid_field_27` – neither on local or production DB's

Why is the entry referencing this table? I'm not sure where the reference (from entry 263) is coming from or how to fix it.

Any help or advice how to remove this error would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using `grid_field_27` as search parameter in channel:entries tag or any of the {if} conditionals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems related to [this bug report](https://expressionengine.com/support/bugs/22873/MySQL-error-when-using-Grid-with-2-content-types-on-the-same-page-and-a-modifier-conditional). If you have a conditional checking for something like this:

```
{if grid_field:total_rows > 0}
```

try changing that to this:

```
{if '{grid_field:total_rows}' > 0}
```